# Fill the remaining categories SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Customer :

```
UserId  Name    Amount
1       AA        1
1       BB        1
1       CC        1
1       DD        1
2       AA        1
2       BB        1
2       CC        1
3       AA        1
3       CC        1
```

And i need select where i will see for every UserID every name (AA,BB,CC,DD) - if he doesnt have a record with that name in the previous table i want too fill the amount with 0. So for given example the result should be:

```
UserId  Name    Amount
1        AA       1
1        BB       1
1        CC       1
1        DD       1
2        AA       1
2        BB       1
2        CC       1
2        DD       0
3        AA       1
3        BB       0
3        CC       1
3        DD       0
```

I dont think i can do that with `"case when..."` so maybe with some join on table with only all names in it..? Thank you for any help

Comment: "join on table with only all names", yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about this in two steps.  First get all the rows, then fill in the values.  The first part uses a `cross join`.  The second can be done with a `left join` (or correlated subquery):

```
select u.userid, n.name, coalesce(.amount, 0) as amount
from (select distinct userid from customer) u cross join
     (select distinct name from customer) n left join
     customer c
     on c.userid = u.userid and c.name = n.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this

```
SELECT B.UserId, A.Name, ISNULL(C.Amount,0) Amount
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM TEMP) A
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT USERID FROM TEMP) B 
LEFT JOIN TEMP C ON B.USERID = C.USERID AND A.NAME = C.NAME
ORDER BY B.USERID, A.NAME
```